# Xamarin Card.IO from Component Store will not compile

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio, card.io

After adding the Card.IO component from the Xamarin Component Store, the following error message occurs while building:

`Error MT1305: The binding library 'Card.IO.dll' contains a user framework (Card.IO.dll), but embedded user frameworks require iOS 8.0 (the deployment target is CardIOSharp.framework). Please set the deployment target in the Info.plist file to at least 8.0. (MT1305) ...`

[image: Error message]

My deployment target is set to 9.2 (>8) as follows

[image: Project options]

Any ideas as to why I am getting this error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Deployment Target is set in `Info.plist` rather than the project settings.

[image: Info.plist screenshot]

Check that this is set to iOS 8.0 or higher as required by the component.

The screenshot is showing your [SDK version](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/compiling_for_different_devices/#SDK_Options) - the version of the SDK that will your app will be built against.

Comment: Thanks @bytesguy, use the "Ios Application" section in Visual Studio and away you go, my bad it was set to 7.0, I blame Fridays :)

Comment: @WickedW Glad I could help :)